# Unable to create MySQL table automatically using Spring Boot

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

Earlier I was able to create a table in MySQL using my program. But now it doesn't seem to be working.
Can someone point out the issue out to me.

**application.properties:**

```
#jdbc
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/motsach
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=123456


#hibernate
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = create
hibernate.current.session.context.class = org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=true
```

**Database Config file:**

```
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.project.form.model" });
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory;
}

private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    properties.put("hibernate.current.session.context.class", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.current.session.context.class"));        
    return properties;
}

@Bean(name ="dataSource")
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
    System.out.println("## getDataSource: " + dataSource);
    return dataSource;
}
```

Comment: Change "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = create" into "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = update". OR its better to just use "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update". no need to add it in hibernateProperties()

Comment: Thank you, but nothing change.

Comment: create should work fine for dropping and creating db at every run

Comment: @D.Doe add spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update". in application.properties file. no need to add it in hibernateProperties()

Comment: Thanks bro, but still error.

Answer (score 1):

With this configuration you can create table automatically during spring boot application start.

```
server.contextPath=/demo-app
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyHbmImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using an `application.yml` file and this worked for me.

[Refered link](https://github.com/TechPrimers/spring-boot-mysql-example/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.yml)

```yaml
# application.yml 
spring:
    datasource:
        driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        password: abcd
        url: jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/sonoo?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
        username: root
    jpa:
        hibernate.ddl-auto: update
        generate-ddl: true
        show-sql: true
```

Comment: Refered from: https://github.com/TechPrimers/spring-boot-mysql-example/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.yml